# Small Pandas DataFrame = bad performance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**Usecase and conclusions**

Create a 2*2 table filled with integers, change the values of one specific row, and access several rows. For this I was planning using pandas DataFrame but got very disappointed with the performances. The conclusion shows an incompressible cost for pandas DataFrame when the data is a small tables:
- pandas.loc = pandas.iloc = 115 µs
- pandas.iat = 5 µs (20 times faster, but only access one cell)
- numpy access = 0.5 (200 times faster, acceptable performance)

Am I doing a incorrect usage of pandas DataFrame ? Is it supposed to be used only for massive tables of data ? Given that my goal is to use a very simple MultiIndexation (type 1, type 2 and date), is there an existing data-structure that would support similar performance that numpy arrays and is as easy as pandas DataFrame ?

Or the other option I consider is to create my own class of MultiIndexed numpy arrays.

**Code of the usecase**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import time
data = [[1,2],[3,4]]
array = np.array(data)
index= pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime(2000,2,2), datetime(2000,2,4)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = index)
```

It takes around **0.1 ms** using pandas using the **loc** function

```
%timeit df.loc[datetime(2000,2,2)] = [12, 42]
115 µs ± 2.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**iloc** has the **same bad performances**, although I would have intuitively think it would be faster

```
%timeit df.iloc[0] = [12, 42]
114 µs ± 3.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Testing iat, we are down to 5 µs, which is more acceptable

```
%timeit df.iat[0,0] = 42
5.03 µs ± 37.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Finally testing the same behavior with a numpy.array, we have excellent performances :

```
%timeit array[0,:] = [12, 42]
705 ns ± 4.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: if you want to push the performance comparison, you can even try `%timeit data[0] = [12, 42]` it is faster which is normal. You could use a `dict` to store your data in a bit more structure way instead of pandas df, they could allow to actually have something similar to multiindexation

Comment: _Am I doing a incorrect usage of pandas DataFrame ?_ You haven't explained what your use case is.